# Local IP address?

Tags: android, ip

I'm building an android app for connecting two devices together, but just as general question: Since we are all connected to a wireless LAN, the IP addresses are local, not global. I'm just wondering if we can connect to a devices using it's local IP address?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Tina: Sure you can. The trick is to use static IP, not DHCP IP, so that it will be clear which client is identified by what IP address.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a multicast to find other devices in the same local network